# API I'm using can't be accessed unless Captcha is completed

Tags: php, api, cookies, captcha, cloudflare

I am trying to access API data from CraftingStore Public API.

When I am trying it on localhost, everything works like it should (1st pic, also printing results for to show).
However, when I am trying to view it on the actual website (2nd pic), it is not working but instead saying to enable cookies and to complete captcha.

When on localhost:

[image: localhost]

When on website:

[image]

Also code for accessing the API:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.craftingstore.net/v7/payments?page=1');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                'token:'.$cs_token
    ));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $obj = json_decode($result);
    $dononame = $obj->data[0]->inGameName;
    $donobuy = $obj->data[0]->packageName;
```

What can I do?

Comment: There probably isn't much you can do from your end. Such an API, if it is supposed to be publicly available, should not be hidden behind that sort of Cloudflare "bot protection" to begin with. I'd contact the API provider for support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite usual for API's with Cloudflare. You'll need to make a page rule for the API domain/URI to disable the Browser Integrity Check.

Source: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200504045-Using-Cloudflare-with-your-API